# Free Marker Template processing want to know data model vs Template variable missing

Tags: templates, freemarker

Can anyone help me about Free Marker Template reading process.
I want to know the missing variables in template when compared to data model which i am getting from database in Map.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_24);
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(filepath));
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
Map confMap = new HashMap();
confMap.put("user", "Sunil");
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.txt");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filepath + "\\template.conf");
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
temp.process(confMap, out);
```

template.txt

```
user=${user}
firstname =${firstname}
lastname =${lastname}
```

Am using the above mentioned code. want to know before process the template that data model vs template.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: my question related to template and data model. e,g am having template with four variables but am passing data model values more than the template variables, so in this scenario want to know how many variables are process.

Answer (score 0):

What data-model variables the template needs only turns out as the template executes. That's because of `#if`-s, `.vars[dynamicName]`-s, etc. Also it's not always obvious that if you have a `${x}` then `x` refers to a data-model variable, or there will be an `x` in another scope (like a global variable) at that point.

You could still do a pretty good guess if you walk the tree of the template though. You can start that with `Tempalte.getRootTreeNode()`. As you will see it's a deprecated API, because backward compatibility is not promised, but it's actually unlikely to have changes in 2.3.x that would break existing code, as far as the code tries to walk the tree with as few assumptions as possible.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know after processing the template, To identify the list of failures variable or data model values

Comment: The template processing is normally aborted with an `InvalidReferenceException` at the first such variable, so you don't get a list that way. To collect multiple missing variables, you should decide how do you want to continue at missing variables. Setting up a `TemplateExceptionHandler` might be an answer.